# Accessing Updated State variables React

Tags: reactjs, state

I am new to react. I am retrieving data from the function Read() and displaying it in the form of a table. I want to edit and delete the data. the problem I am facing is: -

I stored the Axios response into a state variable and mapped it to the table. I have Edit and Delete icons for each row.
I am able to delete the row and after deleting the row I am calling the Read() function to retrieve data (since one row got deleted) and it updates new data without any issue in the table.

But the state variable still holds old data, when clicked on Empedit(child component) still holds the old data.

Note: - I don't want the page to be refreshed, it has to display without loading the page

```
class empData extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.read = this.read.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            empList:[]
        }
        
    read(){
        
        const readData = axios.get('api/readEmp');
        axios.all([readData]).then(function (response) {     
            this.setState({
                empList: response[0].data,
                
            });
        })
    }

    delete(empId){

        axios.get('api/empDelete/${empId}').then(json => {
            if (json.data) {              
                this.read();
            }
        });     
    }


    empTableList(){
        
        return(
            this.state.empList.map(item =>(

            <tr>
                <td>{item.firstName}</td>
                <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td>
    
                    <Empedit  read={this.read}   emp = {item}/>                 
                    <button onClick={this.delete({item.id}) } value="delete"/>

                </td>
            </tr>
            ))
        )
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <table>
                <th>
                    <tr>
                    <td> First Name </td>
                    <td> last Name </td>                                    
                    <td> Operate </td>                                    
                    </tr>
                </th>
            <tbody>
                {this.empTableList()}
            </tbody>

        )
    }
}
export default (empData);
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Comment: thanks for the response, empedit is the child component where I am passing item(object)

Comment: Your `delete`  method should bind to the current this like `read` method since it creates a new function scope to call the read function in callback. Or you can also use arrow function as well `delete = () => {}`

Comment: Apart from @tmhao2005 comment, you should use reserved keywords like delete instead have methods like deleteEmp etc.. Just recommendation.

Comment: thank you guys for your suggestions. I was able to solve this by eliminating the child component and coded on the same page